# ip address or visitors staying long on my website

Tags: php, cpu, cpu-usage, googlebot

i am experiencing heavy CPU usage, i observe that some ip address staying long and hit count also gone above 50000 each and time on website reached 10 hours.

```
ip address          time    hits   page view kb     website
159.0.93.164        10h     37,420  37,413  271 KB  mydomain.co.uk/page101.php
```

please let me know what could be possibilities.

thanks

Comment: Url please? If your users are staying on there for 10 hours at a time, I hafta check this site out!

Comment: Sounds like one or more search engine bots without knowing any more. Their crawl-rates can be even higher than your numbers - check your logs and update your question!

Comment: My guess: bots. This can be confirmed with an usually high number of 404 errors are being generating by the heavy users.

Answer (score 0):

Use fail2ban - it can change your firewall to block an IP after a certain number of attempts in a given time period.  If its a bot, its probably proxied, so you'll need an automated tool like fail2ban to "re-ban" after they rotate to a new IP address.  Sooner or later they'll exhaust their proxy exit point IP addresses.

BTW - that IP resolves to Saudi Telecom - is that expected?

Comment: A blanket ban like that might damage search engine rankings if the OP didn't allow crawling. Use a product by all means, but allow for IP range exceptions.

Comment: Agreed. My guess is its an unwanted visitor - even Googlebot doesn't hammer your site like he/she is suggesting.